# cant simply grab energy history.. firebase complicated

Tags: nest-api

I thought I was versed in web development until I saw firebase. Way too confusing.

All I want to do is grab yesterdays total heating/cooling time from my own device. Can I do this with php?

Then once I have that information I can put it into a database for more than 10 days. Seems Rediculous that the nest only saves 10 days. I want to see how we did this year without house upgrades compared to next year with upgrades.

Answer (score 1):

The Nest API only exposes realtime data, unfortunately historical information is not available.

While it sounds like your use case is for personal use, the Nest Developer Program prohibits third party developers from storing data from the Nest API for more than 10 trailing days according to the [TOS](https://developer.nest.com/documentation/tos).